# Knockout is not calling the function for visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Let say I have,

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>        
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <span data-bind="visible: $parent.checkVisiblity"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
var ViewModel = function() {
this.items = [{name: 'a'},{name: 'b'}];
 this.checkVisiblity = function(item) {
     console.log(item)
     return item.name === 'a';
     }
};
```

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

Why the function checkVisiblity is not called by knockout? How to call this.

http://jsfiddle.net/cPVGg/1/

Comment: Please also check the spelling of `checkVisibility`.  You have it mispelled in the `ViewModel` definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `visible` binding to:

```
<span data-bind="visible: $parent.checkVisibility($data)"></span>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cPVGg/2/ Unable to parse bindings. Message: TypeError: $parent.checkVisibility is not a function; Bindings value: visible: $parent.checkVisibility(this)

Comment: just check in console. BTW, I got the solution with your help, visible: $parent.checkVisiblity($data). Please update your answer

Comment: Please test this with $data and this and see the result.

Comment: I have. I get the same thing as using `this`.

Comment: this parameter is not correct answer. With this, you can see window object in console, http://jsfiddle.net/cPVGg/7/. With $data you can see the correct object in console, http://jsfiddle.net/cPVGg/8/.

Comment: Please check the firebug console. I have checked this many times. For this, window object is logged and for $data, correct object is logged.